# labelStyle:{fontFamily:'Verdana'} does not show

Tags: react-native

I have a DrawerMenu with DrawerOptions that specify the labelStyle like this:

```
const DrawerStyles = {
    drawerPosition:'right',
    drawerBackgroundColor:'#86959a',
    contentOptions:{
        activeTintColor:'white',
        inactiveTintColor:'white',
        labelStyle:{fontFamily:'Verdana',}
    },
};
```

But for some reason, the `Verdana` font doesn't show.  I tried typing in `Times New Roman`, but that also doesn't show.  But if I type `serif`, then that shows. How do I get other font files to show OTHER THAN `serif`?

--

**EDIT**

In IOS, my drawer navigator recognizes the font families assigned to `labelStyle:{fontFamily:'some font'}`.  I even get custom TTF fonts to show.  But in android, it doesn't render.   What's weird that in Android, I can render all my fonts AND custom fonts for ALL components EXCEPT drawer navigation labelstyle font family.   Whereas in IOS, i can get my custom fonts to render ALL the time for all components for iPhone 7 simulator.

Both my ios and android are compiled from the same react-native project/source code.

**Side note:** I do have an issue where fonts don't render at all in iPhone 8 simulator and iPhone X simulator.  That problem is described in this question here:

[React-Native custom fonts don't render in iPhone 8 and above?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48649363/react-native-custom-fonts-dont-render-in-iphone-8-and-above)

Answer (score 13):

If a fontWeight of normal is added to the styles of `labelStyle`, the drawer items renders in the correct fontFamily in both Android and iOS:

```
labelStyle:{ fontWeight: 'normal' }
```

Comment: There. Rolled your comment into the answer for you so you can see what a good answer looks like. Note in particular the absence of "try" and "works for me" :)

Comment: Alright thank you it was my first answer here, i will make sure to to follow your advice.

Comment: Yes, I realised that when your answer was deleted just before I pressed `Add Comment` the *first* time I tried to reply to you and couldn't find another post of yours to add the comment to :) Thought it might be good idea to do a bit of mentoring. Have a read of [Why and how are some answers deleted?](//stackoverflow.com/help/deleted-answers) and [answer] for tips on posting good answers. PS [How do comment @replies work?](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/43019) might also be useful to make sure users are notified when you post a comment  addressed to them.

Answer (score 1):

Not all fonts are available on the mobile platform. You will have to link these fonts by including the font ttf files typically under assets/fonts directory.

Then link these font files by making reference to these in Info.plist (iOS) and package.json files.

Here is a sample project:
https://gitlab.com/applification/react-native-custom-fonts

Comment: That isn't the issue because verdana and times New Roman does render when I use it on other components in the same project.  It just doesn't work when I use it in the labelstyle.  Is there something special about the label style compared to other items that cause it to not accept the same font family?

Comment: Not clear from the context which component you are using. Can you tell me if this is react-navigation one or some other Drawer component?

Comment: Also, the font renders fine in IOS, but not android.  In IOS, I can get custom fonts like `alrightsans-bold,verdana,georgia etc...` to work in ios in both the drawer navigator labelStyle and all other compnents.  But in android, my fonts families don't work for drawer navigator labelStyle, but they do work for ALL OTHER components.

Answer (score 1):

**Use This:**

```
 labelStyle: {
        fontFamily: 'Verdana',
        fontWeight: '200',
        fontSize: 12,
        // color: 'white',
      },
```